# Does C++ deprecate some parts of the Linux API?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am in the middle of reading *The Linux Programming Interface* and *Linux programming by examples*. Both are very good books and explain Linux API very well. But quite often I find myself thinking that in real world projects I would prefer C++ standard library, Boost or some other good C++ library (there are many well written  and portable C++ libs) over C API whenever possible. This naturally bags a question - why do I need to use Linux API directly when good C++ compiler and libs (Boost, TBB and etc) are available on target platforms? I guess the same could be said about Windows API too, but I don't know much about Windows system programing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not new to C++.  In C, there have been two ways to open files for a long, long time:

```
// Only on POSIX
int fdes = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
```

Or:

```
// Any hosted C environment, POSIX or otherwise
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
```

So why would anyone ever use the POSIX-specific version?  The answer is simple -- there are a large number of system calls which work with POSIX file descriptors.  For example, `select`.  You can also make things other than files, like pipes and sockets, and you can pass them to other processes.  There is a long tradition of using POSIX file descriptors, and we have a large number of books and references on how to do network programming with them.

So the trade-off is between the portable version and the powerful version.  It always has been.

**The other half of this** is that time you work with files on Linux you are working with the POSIX interface.  Libraries just hide it from you.  Boost uses it, the C runtime uses it, the JRE uses it, and GHC uses it.  Many (most?) language runtimes are written in C, and direct access to the system calls is preferred.

Comment: The trade-off is also between ease-of-use/safety and power. The Boost libraries chip off a bit of the power argument, though, esp. with its ASIO sockets library.

Comment: @larsmans: Unfortunately, ASIO is usually the wrong tool for the job on Linux.  ASIO is also just one API of many under the POSIX umbrella.

Comment: @Dietrich: Boost.Asio and POSIX ASIO are vastly different things. IIRC Boost.Asio does not even use the POSIX ASIO API.

Comment: My mistake.  However, for example, you can't kqueue a pty on OS X, which either means you avoid kqueue or shove the pty somewhere else.  I'm not sure how transparent Boost could make that ("law of leaky abstractions" as Jan Hudec mentioned below).  So Boost has to sacrifice performance or portability in some cases.

Comment: Any comments why Windows doesn't support POSIX?

Comment: @pic11: Windows does support POSIX, to an extent.  Or it did, partially, depending on what version (2000, 7 Ultimate, etc.) and what add-ons you installed (UNIX Services for Windows).  POSIX is really Unix, and so Microsoft added a POSIX compatibility layer to Windows to support applications originally developed for Unix.  Apple took the opposite approach when developing OS X: they made the POSIX interface the primary interface and turned the existing Mac OS APIs (Carbon) and made them into compatibility APIs, which have since been deprecated or dropped.

Answer (score 3):

You should use higher level API whenever possible. It's usually faster to work with and makes it easier to port your code to another platform. However:

1. Due to the [law of leaky abstractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) it's useful to know the underyling operating system API so you understand various quirks and performance issues that the higher level API was not able to hide.
2. Some things are not doable with the portable API, usually because it's so different between operating systems that it's not easily possible.
3. All portable APIs incur some overhead. In a big project it's small compared to the rest of the code, but if you are doing something small, you might want to avoid that overhead, especially if you know you'll need to use the specific API somewhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard is not published for a particular platform. It is platform independent, So If you are going to use some platform features/functionality you will have to use platform dependent feature/functionality usually called `system` api. So in that sense No the C++ library does not deprecate linux/windows api.